# Linux user for audit purpose

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Is it possible to create a user, with a read only root privilege, so the user can see the entire file system, but won't be able to change anything?

This is for both audit and troubleshooting scenarios, we want grant someone to investigate, but don't want them to mess up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to give a user permission to entire file system. However, we can give the user permission limited to few directories using ACL.

Like,

```
setfacl -R -m u:readOnlyUser:r /var/log
```

- `-R` to give permission recursively
- `-m` to modify ACL
- `u` Modification for user (readOnlyUser)
- `r` give only read permission

Likewise, we can give to multiple directories.

Comment: Hi, msp9011. Appreciate for your reply,

Comment: As I was thinking troubleshooting will involve a lot of parts in the OS, the user may need a higher privilege. Then I noticed most parts in linux OS is readable to the user, for example `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` for network troubleshooting is also readable.  I think your answer is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to audit? Most information you require might be avaliable in system or application logs. If not, see if that can be configured (or the applications modified to log relevant activity). Unixy systems are standard fare as servers for quite some time now, it would be very unusual if your requirements didn't itch somebody before. Search/ask for your specific requirements. It probably pays off to segment such data, to be able to limit access on need-to-know basis.

Comment: Should that not be a comment, rather than an answer ... ?

Comment: Hi VonBrrand, thank you for the comment. I was thinking for audit user, they should be able to run whatever command they want, whatever files they want to see in the system, but in a `non destruction manner`, so they can ensure the safety of the system. Similarly for our troubleshoot user, we want them to gather whatever information they want to resolve the issue. In my comment to msp9011, I realized most of the files are readable, I think that level of privilege is adequate already, any additional special access can be granted per msp9011 recommendation.